# Installing software via CVS, but I don't have /srv on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cvs

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8, and I'm trying to compile a software package originally developed for Linux.

The code is under development and uses a CVS repository and is attempting to access  `/srv/cvs/CVSROOT/history`, but I don't have a `/srv` directory.

Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: To those considering voting this closed and moving this to SO, this belongs *here*.

Comment: But it has the words compile and code in it!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the software, there may be a way to change the location of the CVS repository. That might be a configure flag or an environment variable.

But if not, you can just create the directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/cvs
sudo chown USER /srv/cvs
```

Replace USER with whatever user needs to own the repository. Then, as that user, initialize the CVS repository like this

```
sudo su USER -c "CVSROOT=/srv/cvs cvs init"
```